# Path to image in js with wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, wp-localize-script

I'm trying to implement animated [svg icons](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/05/animated-svg-icons-with-snap-svg/) into my Wordpress theme.
All's is great, except I can't figure out how to put proper url for svg images in this js file:

```
var svgIconConfig = {
    plus : { 
        url : 'svg/plus.svg',
        animation : [
            { 
                el : 'path:nth-child(1)', 
                animProperties : { 
                    from : { val : '{"transform" : "r0 32 32", "opacity" : 1}' }, 
                    to : { val : '{"transform" : "r180 32 32", "opacity" : 0}' }
                } 
            },
            { 
                el : 'path:nth-child(2)', 
                animProperties : { 
                    from : { val : '{"transform" : "r0 32 32"}' }, 
                    to : { val : '{"transform" : "r180 32 32"}' }
                } 
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Here is what I've tried:

in functions.php

```
function svgicons_config() {
  wp_register_script('svgicons-config', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/svgicons-config.js', array(), '1.0.0', 'true'); // Custom scripts
  wp_enqueue_script('svgicons-config');
}

$svg_path = array( 'template_url' => get_bloginfo('template_url') );
wp_localize_script( 'svgicons-config', 'svg_path', $svg_path );

add_action('init', 'svgicons_config');
```

And in svgicons-config.js:

```
url : 'svg_path.template_url+"/svg/plus.svg"',
```

and few more variations of this. But no luck. I'm almost sure that I'm making some stupid mistake in this part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you shouldn't use `get_bloginfo('template_url')`, but rather `get_template_directory_uri()` or it's `*_stylesheet_*()` equivalent, it's a JavaScript problem: The localized object shouldn't be wrapped in quotes:

```
// Wrong
url : 'svg_path.template_url+"/svg/plus.svg"',

// Right:
url : svg_path.template_url + "/svg/plus.svg",
```

When handling JavaScript, simply use `console.log( svg_path )` in your script to see the output in your browsers developer tools  console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @kaiser! Well, I did try get_template_directory_uri() and url without quotes before with no luck. Now, when you've explained what is the right way, I tried again - svg_path is not defined.

Comment: @Baltar You'll have to put the call to `wp_localize_script()` exactly after the call to `wp_enqueue_script()` _inside_ your function.